# Hadoop resource manager page cannot be opened from Windows WSL

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, wsl-2

I have used this page to install and run Hadoop on Windows WSL Ubuntu-22.04: https://linuxhint.com/install-apache-hadoop-ubuntu/.
Looks like the Hadoop has started:

```
hadoopuser@hostname:~$ jps
1840 NodeManager
993 NameNode
1409 SecondaryNameNode
2355 Jps
1685 ResourceManager
1148 DataNode
```

But I cannot open the Resource manager page at http://127.0.0.1:8088/ - the error is:

```
This site can’t be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
```

Another Hadoop page at http://127.0.0.1:9870/dfshealth.html#tab-overview does work.

In the instructions, there are steps to permit the both ports through the firewall:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=9870/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8088/tcp
```

but I haven't managed to run them successfully. Yet, as I said, the page at `9870` can be viewed even without these steps.

I suppose this is something related to WSL.

I am opening pages with `xdg-open http://127.0.0.1:8088`

Comment: What does `netstat -tlp` show? Is RM listening on port 8088?

Comment: The WSL2 firewall is not the same as forwarding ports for the windows hypervisor... You want to look at using netsh portproxy